# template function with default value

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& container = {}) {
  // ... some implementation
}
```

Now I can call

```
foo<std::vector>(some_vector_param) or foo<std::map>(some_map_param)
```

As I have default value for the container, I should be able to call without any param.

```
foo()
```

But at this point, the compiler doesn't know how to translate it as it could be a vector or a map. One solution is to explicitly specify the type.

```
foo<vector>()
```

Is there a way for me to avoid that? Can I let the compiler use vector if the input type is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template parameters can have default argument too:

```
template <typename T = vector<int>>
void foo(const T& container = {}) {
  // ... some implementation
  }
```